# Why can't I change my Github repo description from their site?

Tags: git, github, repository

What's the problem with Github? I can't see any option to change my repository description on their site. Also, new to Linux and command line stuff, and changing the `description` file through vi also didn't do any change on github.com.

Downloaded GitHub for Desktop, I see I can only create new repositories, but **no** option to edit a current one.

Didn't find any tutorials on YouTube, and also no documentation on how to edit an existing repo using their Windows App.

What can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+change+description

Answer (score 7):

Try clicking on the gear icon on your repo home page:
[image]